# Select range and download output table on shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I will detail this issue to make it clearer to you. I'm going to present two codes: the first code is basically a function that calculates the coefficient values for all the dates in my `date2`, as you'll see. After that, I use the `write_xlsx` function to download the results to my laptop.

In the second code I use the same function as in code 1, however I integrated it with shiny. Here, that's the question I want help with: my idea is that the person can insert an interval between the dates of my `date2` and that he can download the result in excel as I'm doing in code 1.

Example: I have 3 dates in my `date2`, that is 30/06, 01/07 and 02/07, but the person may want to see only the period between 30/06 and 01/07 and do not want to see 02/07, for this I thought of using `daterange`. Could you help me do something in this sense: that is, the person chooses an interval between the dates of `date2` and she can download output table

**First code (Just function)**

```
library(dplyr)
library(writexl)

df1 <- structure(
 list(date1= c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
     date2 = c("2021-06-30","2021-06-30","2021-07-01","2021-07-02"),
    Category = c("FDE","ABC","FDE","ABC"),
   Week= c("Wednesday","Wednesday","Friday","Friday"),
  DR1 = c(4,1,6,1),
 DR01 = c(4,1,4,4), DR02= c(4,2,6,0),DR03= c(9,5,4,0),
 DR04 = c(5,4,3,5),DR05 = c(5,4,5,0),
 DR06 = c(2,4,3,5),DR07 = c(2,5,4,0),
 DR08 = c(3,4,5,0),DR09 = c(2,3,4,0)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

return_coef <- function(dmda, CategoryChosse) {
  
  x<-df1 %>% select(starts_with("DR0"))
  
  x<-cbind(df1, setNames(df1$DR1 - x, paste0(names(x), "_PV")))
  PV<-select(x, date2,Week, Category, DR1, ends_with("PV"))
  
  med<-PV %>%
    group_by(Category,Week) %>%
    summarize(across(ends_with("PV"), median))
  
  SPV<-df1%>%
    inner_join(med, by = c('Category', 'Week')) %>%
    mutate(across(matches("^DR0\\d+$"), ~.x + 
                    get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')),
                  .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
    select(date1:Category, DR01_DR01_PV:last_col())
  
  SPV<-data.frame(SPV)
  
  mat1 <- df1 %>%
    filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
    select(starts_with("DR0")) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
    arrange(desc(row_number())) %>%
    mutate(cs = cumsum(value)) %>%
    filter(cs == 0) %>%
    pull(name)
  
  (dropnames <- paste0(mat1,"_",mat1, "_PV"))
  
  SPV <- SPV %>%
    filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
    select(-any_of(dropnames))
  
  datas<-SPV %>%
    filter(date2 == ymd(dmda)) %>%
    group_by(Category) %>%
    summarize(across(starts_with("DR0"), sum)) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols= -Category, names_pattern = "DR0(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
    mutate(name = readr::parse_number(name))
  colnames(datas)[-1]<-c("Days","Numbers")
  
  datas <- datas %>% 
    group_by(Category) %>% 
    slice((as.Date(dmda) - min(as.Date(df1$date1) [
      df1$Category == first(Category)])):max(Days)+1) %>%
    ungroup
  
  mod <- nls(Numbers ~ b1*Days^2+b2,start = list(b1 = 0,b2 = 0),data = datas, algorithm = "port")
  as.numeric(coef(mod)[2])
  
}
Test<-cbind(df1 %>% select(date2,Category), coef = mapply(return_coef, df1$date2, df1$Category))
> Test
       date2 Category coef
1 2021-06-30      FDE    4
2 2021-06-30      ABC    1
3 2021-07-01      FDE    6
4 2021-07-02      ABC    1

write_xlsx(Test, 'C:/Users/Jose/Desktop/example.xlsx') #  I do this to download the output table on my computer.
```

**Second code (Function with Shiny)**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)

function.test<-function(){
  
df1 <- structure(
 list(date1= c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
     date2 = c("2021-06-30","2021-06-30","2021-07-01","2021-07-02"),
    Category = c("FDE","ABC","FDE","ABC"),
   Week= c("Wednesday","Wednesday","Friday","Friday"),
  DR1 = c(4,1,6,1),
 DR01 = c(4,1,4,4), DR02= c(4,2,6,0),DR03= c(9,5,4,0),
 DR04 = c(5,4,3,5),DR05 = c(5,4,5,0),
 DR06 = c(2,4,3,5),DR07 = c(2,5,4,0),
 DR08 = c(3,4,5,0),DR09 = c(2,3,4,0)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

return_coef <- function(dmda, CategoryChosse) {
  
  x<-df1 %>% select(starts_with("DR0"))
  
  x<-cbind(df1, setNames(df1$DR1 - x, paste0(names(x), "_PV")))
  PV<-select(x, date2,Week, Category, DR1, ends_with("PV"))
  
  med<-PV %>%
    group_by(Category,Week) %>%
    summarize(across(ends_with("PV"), median))
  
  SPV<-df1%>%
    inner_join(med, by = c('Category', 'Week')) %>%
    mutate(across(matches("^DR0\\d+$"), ~.x + 
                    get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')),
                  .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
    select(date1:Category, DR01_DR01_PV:last_col())
  
  SPV<-data.frame(SPV)
  
  mat1 <- df1 %>%
    filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
    select(starts_with("DR0")) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
    arrange(desc(row_number())) %>%
    mutate(cs = cumsum(value)) %>%
    filter(cs == 0) %>%
    pull(name)
  
  (dropnames <- paste0(mat1,"_",mat1, "_PV"))
  
  SPV <- SPV %>%
    filter(date2 == dmda, Category == CategoryChosse) %>%
    select(-any_of(dropnames))
  
  datas<-SPV %>%
    filter(date2 == ymd(dmda)) %>%
    group_by(Category) %>%
    summarize(across(starts_with("DR0"), sum)) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols= -Category, names_pattern = "DR0(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
    mutate(name = readr::parse_number(name))
  colnames(datas)[-1]<-c("Days","Numbers")
  
  datas <- datas %>% 
    group_by(Category) %>% 
    slice((as.Date(dmda) - min(as.Date(df1$date1) [
      df1$Category == first(Category)])):max(Days)+1) %>%
    ungroup
  
  mod <- nls(Numbers ~ b1*Days^2+b2,start = list(b1 = 0,b2 = 0),data = datas, algorithm = "port")
  as.numeric(coef(mod)[2])
  
}
}

Test<-cbind(df1 %>% select(date2,Category), coef = mapply(return_coef, df1$date2, df1$Category))


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                          br(),
                          
                          tabPanel("",
                                   sidebarLayout(
                                     sidebarPanel(
                                       
                                      dateRangeInput("daterange", "Period you want to see:",
                                                      start = "2001-01-01",
                                                      end   = "2010-12-31"),
                                       br(),
                                       
                                       
                                     ),
                                     
                                     mainPanel(
                                       tabsetPanel()
                                       ),
                                     ))
                          ))#)


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  data <- reactive(function.test())
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you already have the `Test` data -

```
Test <- structure(list(date2 = structure(c(18808, 18808, 18809, 18810
), class = "Date"), Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC"), 
    coef = c(4, 1, 6, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

You can build the shiny code to download specific dataset as -

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                          br(),
                          tabPanel("",
                                   sidebarLayout(
                                     sidebarPanel(
                                       uiOutput('daterange'),
                                       br()
                                       
                                     ),
                                     mainPanel(
                                         dataTableOutput('table'),
                                         br(), br(), 
                                         downloadButton("dl", "Download")
                                     ),
                                   ))
  ))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  data <- reactive(Test)
  
  data_subset <- reactive({
    req(input$daterange1)
    days <- seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = 'day')
    subset(data(), date2 %in% days)
  })
  
  output$daterange <- renderUI({
    dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Period you want to see:",
                   start = min(data()$date2),
                   end   = max(data()$date2))
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    data_subset()
  })
  
  output$dl <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { "data.xlsx"},
    content = function(file) {
      writexl::write_xlsx(data_subset(), path = file)
      }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Ronak, can you see please this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70616161/how-to-adjust-error-using-observe-function-in-a-shiny-app